# Computed Property with callback returns 'undefined'

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to evaluate some state external to my app in run-time, and using that do determine/drive the value of a computed property. It seems however that my property always returns 'undefined'. Am I making some serious definition error, and should this not be possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. A cleaned up snippet of code doing the calculations:

```
curState: function() {
  if (this.authenticated) {
    return true;
  } else {
    external_getStatus( function(status) {
      if (status === 'allowed') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}.property()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `curState` when `this.authenticated` is `false`. The `if` statement

```
if (status === 'allowed') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

returns from the callback given to `external_getStatus()`. You have to put a `return` statement into `curState` to get a non-`undefined` return value.

Also, as an aside, it's better style to write `return status === 'allowed'` instead of the above `if` statement.

Comment: The first part makes absolute sense, thanks! A little unsure on how to get the values out of the async call as a return value though.